# Banner Rotation Issue Joomla 3.7.3

Tags: joomla-3.7

I have a banner module that shows 5 banners, and pulls from a single category, but multiple clients. Basically, the layout is 5 banners on top of each other, in a column.

The issue I have is that I want the 5 banners to rotate each time the page reloads. Currently, there is a delay in rotation. What I mean is, if I wait 45 seconds and click refresh the banners rotate no problem. But if I refresh within 20-30 seconds, nothing changes.

My client wants the banners to rotate every refresh. I guess they think some user is frantically clicking "refresh" to see the same 5 banners rotate, I don't know. ???

My question is: what can I change to make the banners rotate on each refresh no matter how soon?

On my module I have:

```
Advanced > Cache: No caching
Advance > Cache Time: 0
```

On General Configuration, under System I have these settings:

```
Cache Handler: File
Path to Cache Folder: (default)
Cache Time: 1
Platform Specific Caching: No
System Cache: OFF - Caching disabled
```

Are there any other settings I am missing that I could adjust?

Thanks,

Melvins138

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the page cache plugin...

```
Extensions -> Plugin Manager -> System - Page Cache
```

This is quite heavy caching, and so should be unpublished for what you want to achieve.

Also, try ftping into the site and looking in the /cache folder.  If all caching is off, this should just have a `index.html` file.

If that folder is empty, then it might be your server doing the caching rather than Joomla itself.

You should really be able to do what you want even if progressive caching is being used elsewhere.

Comment: This appears to be the solution. Thank you.